# missing libv4l2.h file during compilation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm trying to compile a package on an odroid but get the error that I'm missing libv4l2.h that is a dependency for the camera driver package I'm installing (http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera). I have already installed and tested the package on my desktop computer, but my cameras will be connected to the Odroid.

I have installed the v4l2 using the

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

command. I thought this would install all the files and headers I needed but apparently not. I can't remember to have done anything else on my desktop to get it working. Anyone have any tips on this? I think there are some other .h files missing as well, but I don't think the compiler picked them up as the compilation was terminated due to this error

Here is the error I receive

```
In file included from /root/catkin_ws/src/camera_umd/uvc_camera/src/stereo.cpp:6:0:/root/catkin_ws/src/camera_umd/uvc_camera/include/uvc_cam/uvc_cam.h:26:21: fatal error: libv4l2.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287589/missing-libv4l2.h-file-during-compilation/) by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2018-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out
I had to install the following

```
apt-get install libv4l-dev
```

---

Originally posted by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) with karma: 108 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-05**:
What process did you use to setup your build environment? If `rosdep` didn't install those dependencies then something would seem to be incorrectly setup on the `uvc_camera` side.

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2018-04-05**:
I used `catkin build` if that is what you mean. Didn't use `rosdep` prior to that. Maybe that would have fixed it automatically?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-05**:
Yes. Just cloning a repository is not enough. See #q252478 for the general procedure (adapt pkg and ROS version names).

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2018-04-05**:
Thank you! I've just been fiddeling blindly around until it works :D This will make things easier!